# Venom and companions

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Accidentally I quick-saved the game after a fight against a swarm of cazadors. I didn't recognize that my companion, Rex, was poisoned and remained with only 41 hp. He dies after 15 seconds of savegame loading.

I have spent 15 stimpacks in order to prevent him die after quick-save loading (he dies after 15s with no stimpacks) and loading a previous savegame was not in discussion because I made more than 1 hour before.

Are other possibilities to cure companions from venom? It seems they are affected more then me by continuously damage.

**Update**: Forgot to say that I play on PC in hardcore mode.

Comment: Companions don't die; they get knocked unconscious. Just wait for Rex to regain consciousness.

Comment: @amazed: They die on Hardcore mode. Quite permanently.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I guess now everyone knows that I'm too chicken to play on hardcore mode ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry.  Assuming that you are on hardcore mode, you will just have to suck up the stimpack loss.  You could try giving him some antivenom and seeing if he will use it, but I didn't manage to get that to work.

On the other hand, 15 stimpacks is not so bad.  You should be able to handle the loss :).

Comment: Companions don't use antivenom. You should avoid fighting Cazadores with Rex or Veronica, since they fight unarmed and are more likely to be poisoned.

Comment: Yes, you can... you should already be able to see it when you look at the things that are available for crafting.  It's not an unlockable.

Comment: I tried to fast travel immediately to different locations, but no way. Stimpacks are the only solution, I will try to be more careful in future.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but someone else will come upon it some day...

I played on the Xbox hardcore and found occasionally that Veronica would die from poisoning. She is *supposed* to heal the poison once the battle is over but it doesn't always happen. What you can do in that case is one of the following:

- keep her alive with Stimpaks until the next battle, after which she will hopefully heal the poison once the battle is complete
- release her from your party - she will go back to where you found her and will be healed